# Query on Parent Child messages

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have one table Messages which holds parent and its child messages.
Table:
    mid  parentid  subject      msgbody
    1      null      main         test
    2        1       subreply      ..
    3      null      test          ..
    4        1       subreply      ..

```
So here, output should be like

mid    parentid    subject    msgbody   counts
4         1        subreply    ..         3
3        null      test        ..         0
```

I tried with query below for not exists but confused with count and fetching only latest record from it.

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblMessages MInner WHERE MInner.ParentId = M.MessageId)
```

In my output, message id 1 and 2 is not available because I want to display recent and latest message in my messages queue.

In my sample data message queue becomes for messageid 1. and total 3 counts for 3 messages which I want to display.

Please help me out on this query.

Answer (score 0):

Finally done with the help of row number using CTE. Thanks